# Convert table having string column, array column to all string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a table containing string columns and array columns to a table with string columns only

```
Here is how current table looks like:

+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|col1 |         col2       |         col3       |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|   1 |[2,3]               | [4,5]              |
|   2 |[6,7,8]             | [8,9,10]           |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+




How can I get expected result like that:

+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|col1 |         col2       |         col3       |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|   1 | 2                  | 4                  |
|   1 | 3                  | 5                  |
|   2 | 6                  | 8                  |
|   2 | 7                  | 9                  |
|   2 | 8                  | 10                 |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through the [tour] and review [ask]. You will need to provide a [mcve] if you want users to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion comes from mixing scalar columns and list columns.

Under the assumption that -for every row- col2 and col3 are of the same length, we can first translate all scalar columns into list columns and then concatenate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 
                   'col2': [[2,3] , [6,7,8]], 
                   'col3': [[4,5], [8,9,10]]})

# First, we turn all columns into list columns
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [x]) * df['col2'].apply(len)

# Then we concatenate the lists
df.apply(np.concatenate)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0   1   2   4
1   1   3   5
2   2   6   8
3   2   7   9
4   2   8   10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have solved the problem in different ways but it's not effective like what you did ( a great job of you)

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 
                   'col2': [[2,3] , [6,7,8]], 
                   'col3': [[4,5], [8,9,10]]})

df = df[['col1', 'col2']].values

col12 = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(len(df[i][1])):
        col12.append(((df[i][0]), (df[i][1][j])))

col12 = pd.DataFrame([np.append(*row) for row in col12], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(col12)

Answer (score 0):

Conver the columns to lists and after that to `numpy.array`, finally convert them to a `DataFrame`:

```
vals1 = np.array(df.col2.values.tolist())
vals2 = np.array(df.col3.values.tolist())

col1 = np.repeat(df.col1, vals1.shape[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((col1, vals1.ravel(), vals2.ravel())), columns=df.columns)

print(df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     4
1     1     3     5
2     2     6     8
3     2     7     9
```

Comment: I think the code should be different if the shape of array is not identical for all arrays.